# Is size() still faster than EXISTS in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I found [this guide](https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-2-query-tuning/) on query tuning for Neo4j 2.2, and one of the tips in the guide is that when finding whether a relationship exists, this query:

```
size((n)-[:DIRECTED]->()) <> 0
```

is faster than this query:

```
EXISTS((n)-[:DIRECTED]->())
```

To me, it seems counter-intuitive that finding the total number of relationships is faster than determining whether the relationship exists at all. My question is- has `EXISTS` been optimized in later versions of Neo4j so that this tip is no longer necessary? And if not, what is the difference between these two functions that enables size() to be so much faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cypher query planners undergo continuous improvement, and the cited performance difference (that existed in neo4j 2.2) no longer exists.

For example, using [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) in neo4j 3.4.1, these 2 queries now produce essentially the same efficient execution plan (using the degree count):

```
PROFILE
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE SIZE((n)-[:DIRECTED]->()) > 0
RETURN count(*);

PROFILE
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE EXISTS((n)-[:DIRECTED]->())
RETURN count(*);
```